# How can i fix the width issue of this page

Tags: css

Scroll the following page to right and you will see the following

[image: css issue]

What rule is causing the page to be that large and how can i fix it

[Site is here](http://www.servergreek.com/)

Comment: what do you want to achive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a horizontal scroll, because you positioned the div.features with left:350px;

Answer (score 1):

Set `display: inline-block` to `<div class="features"`

UPDATE

It took about 10 seconds to find out where is the problem

[image]

Please use browser debug tools before posting such obvious questions

Answer (score 0):

Add `overflow-x: hidden;` to your `HTML` element for a quick fix.